# Android: Decode images causes GC_FOR_ALLOC all time

Tags: android

When i try to an image decode with BitmapFactory it cause GC_FOR_ALLOC all the time, and then the application crashed OutOfMemory.

**Any suggestion for fix it?** I need to solve this problem for a GridView with a lot of images (381 images 90k each one).

My code from AsyncTask:

```
@Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            data = params[0];
            final Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    context.getResources(), data, 100, 100);
            addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(params[0]), bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

And my decodeSampledBitmapFromResource method:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

Comment: use discCache instead memorycache

Comment: I don't know what is that of discCache. I was find for it but only find a library. Only one thing: I tried to do the same without adding to cache and the LogCat say me all time the same. So, I think the problem isn't cache. Anyway, say me how to transform memorycache to disccache please, because I think that it is a good idea.

Comment: Please, anyone can help me? I really change all code and I don't know why the application give me all time GC.... It's possible that the problem is the LruChache, but I don't know how to change it to DiscCache because this is not a Android direct method and my files aren't storaged, are all drawables.

I need help really soon! :S

Comment: its obviously gonna happen cause you are loading this much images, and dont have to worry about this is only done because android have little memory so it frees up some memory!

Comment: My problem is that when there are too many memory usage the application crash... And I think that GC is the problem and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are the same size you can resize into an unused old bitmap (you'll need to keep a referance counter so you can know when it's no longer in use by the gridview).

See https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Also if you run out of memory with the code you have now your memory cache is likely too big... Use a heap dump or something like it to find out whats leaking.